# HTML Hidden button is still clickable if the user clicks in the area where the button appears

Tags: php, html

I created a makeshift hide/show menu in HTML/CSS using a checkbox, it works great to hide and show text and links, but I have a section where I'd like to show a button when the "checkbox" is clicked. At first it looks great, the button is hidden and when the user clicks the checkbox, a button appears below it. My problem that I'm having is that if the user clicks below the checkbox where the button appears before the button actually appears, they can still trigger the button. Any idea?

```
<td>
<label class="collapsible">
<input type="checkbox" />
<span class="collapser">Edit</span>
<span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
<div class="collapsed">
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="pwd" name="deleteid" value='. $value["id"] . '>
<button onclick="return confirm_delete();" type="submit" name="DelBidSubmit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_delete() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete that?");
    }
</script></form></div></label></td>
```

Heres my CSS code just in case

```
.collapsible {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.collapsible input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.collapsible input:focus ~ .collapser {
  border-color: grey;
}
.collapsible .collapser {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px transparent dotted;

}

.collapsible .arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}
.collapsible input:checked ~ .arrow,
.collapsible input:checked ~ .collapser .arrow {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.collapsible .collapsed {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* fade out, then shrink */
  transition: opacity 0.25s, margin 0.5s 0.25s, font-size 0.5s 0.25s, padding 0.5s 0.25s;
}
.collapsible input:checked ~ .collapsed {
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* grow, then fade in */
  transition: margin 0.25s, padding 0.25s, font-size 0.25s, opacity 0.5s 0.25s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use {display: none}; and {display: block} to handle show/hide actions. Remove opacity:0 and opacity:1 from your styles and replace display:none and display:block styles.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to handle button click if checkbox is selected?

Comment: No, I only wanted to display the button when the checkbox was selected.  It's my "makeshift" way I coded a long time ago to hide/show data. This button is part of a whole bunch of other information that is displayed when the user clicks the checkbox.

Comment: Hey also wondering, do you know how I could add a text input field instead of the button? the text input field isnt showing